# Batch File: Variable being resolved in set command, before I call it

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, errorlevel

I want to create a logging system: Add `%Logger%` after a command to get logs. With only error output, error count.

I want it go get `%Errorlevel%` from the previous program when i call `%Logger%` (EG: I want to get `%Errorlevel%` from `del nul` when i run `del nul %Logger%`)
I have this code:

```bat
Set Logger=2^>CurrentError.log ^>^>%LogName% ^& set Err=%Errorlevel% ^& (for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (CurrentError.log) do (echo [EROR] %%a) ^>^> ErrorConsole.log) ^& (if exist ErrorConsole.log type ErrorConsole.log) ^& type CurrentError.log ^>^>%LogName% ^& (if exist ErrorConsole.log del ErrorConsole.log) ^& (if %Err% GTR 0 set /a ErrNum=ErrNum+1 ^>nul ^& echo %ESC%[33m[WARN] An error has occurred, installation will continue.%ESC%[91m)
```

When i run the code, `%Errorlevel%` is already resolved as it's value in `%Logger%`.

If i use `%%Errorlevel%%`, `%Errorlevel%` is not solved but when i call `%Logger%`, `%Errorlevel%` is a string, not being resolved as it's value (`%Errorlevel%` still `%Errorlevel%`, not 0 or 1)

Comment: Why is everything escaped and on one line?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Only one line because cmd will not execute 2nd line of variable when i call it and escaped to set the special chars in the variable.

Comment: Why are you using a variable for a function instead of a function? And why not just add `> log.txt` to the end of commands?

Comment: Doing like that the log will not contains errors and if you 2>log.log, no output. So you need to add type and a lot in every end of command and hard editing. So i set them to a variable for easy edit and optimize batch size.

Comment: My immediate response is why! Anyhow, you're using the value of a variable before it is evaluated, what you want is the variable itself, so please try `%%Errorlevel%%` instead, you could also use `%%LogName%%`  and `%%ESC%%` too!

Comment: I tried and wrote the issue with `%%Errorlevel%%` that when i call it, it is not resolved with it's value, still `%Errorlevel%`

Comment: You're also not using the recommeded syntax for defining a variable, i.e. `Set "VariableName=String Value"`.

Comment: And all of that stuff in your single line variable makes absolutely no sense to me. It looks as if it is supposed to be for handling `StdErr`, but it is going to parse through all of that for every single use of `%Logger%` regardless of whether the output was `StdOut` and went straight to `%LogName%`. It also looks as if you're defining variables within parenthesized blocks and trying to use them without delaying their expansion!

Comment: Are you executing this line in a batch file or directly in command prompt, and how? Anyway, you'll need [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for `Err` when you expect to read the value you have written before in the same line. Alternatively, just read `ErrorLevel` rather than storing its value in `Err`...

Comment: Read the content before comment. First i redirect it to 2 files then i process error output to add `[EROR]` to the beginning then i write the error to the console and if error occurred, add 1 to `ErrNum` and WARN user. If i read `errorlevel` without set it, it will read the `type` command, not the command i want

Comment: Can you give me example for DelayedExpansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "ESC="
set "ErrNum=0"
set "LogName=Stdout.log"

set Logger=2^>CurrentError.log ^>^> "%LogName%" ^&^
 set "Err=^!Errorlevel^!" ^&^
 (for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (CurrentError.log) do echo [EROR] %%a) ^>^> ErrorConsole.log ^&^
 (if exist ErrorConsole.log type ErrorConsole.log) ^&^
 type CurrentError.log ^>^> "%LogName%" ^&^
 (if exist ErrorConsole.log del ErrorConsole.log) ^&^
 (if ^^!Err^^! NEQ 0 set /a "ErrNum+=1" ^& echo %ESC%[33m[WARN] An error has occurred, installation will continue.%ESC%[91m)

del nul %Logger%
pause
```

The value of `ESC` may not display though it does exist.

Delayed expansion used as the `logger` variable, with code as value is to be used on the same line as the command. Delayed expansion variables use syntax `!name!` instead of `%name%`.

`^` used at end of lines to continue to next line. `set Logger=...` viewed easier over multiple lines.

! escaped as needed i.e. `^!` if within a string, else `^^!`.

Changed `set /a ErrNum=ErrNum+1` to equivalent `set /a "ErrNum+=1"`.

Comment: The value of `ESC` copies from edit view and preview, though from post view does not. May need to insert the value into the pasted code of your editor if it does not exist there.

Comment: ESC is ESC character that i set it for colors

Comment: Very thanks for your help. You forgot to add `()` to the `if`s overwise the 2nd and + `if` will only execute if the first `if` is true.